# Best-Subset Regression based on BIC versus Forward Selection based on AIC

Tags: statistics, regression

I am trying to get a better grasp of BIC and AIC scores. I know BIC has a harsher penalty than AIC regarding model size (it prefers smaller, less complex models).

Suppose there is a situation where I am working with my friend to predict "score" from 8 predictor variables.

**Using best-subset regression based on BIC**, I find out that my best model (lowest BIC)is one that has 2 predictors- "hours_studied" and "number_of_questions_practiced". I also find the best one-predictor model just for fun and it turns out the predictor there is "hours_of_sleep_before_exam".

My friend sees my results but now wants to try another method. She wants to do **forward selection based on AIC**.

**Is there any chance she have the same model as mine?**

I know that forward selection starts with an intercept only model. It falls under stepwise selection and so it means that my friend would start by checking all potential one predictor models, select the one with lowest AIC and then add a second predictor and so on. I think this process would lead to her having the same one-predictor model as mine because she would see my result too and she would agree that "score" predicted using "hours_of_sleep_before_exam" is the best one-predictor model. Once she decides on this, "hours_of_sleep_before_exam" is going to be part of her model no matter what and so no matter what second predictor she chooses, she wont get the same two predictor model as mine. **However, is there any scenario that she might get the same two predictor model as mine?**

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Just in case this question gets no response, one might try the [statistics site](https://stats.stackexchange.com).

Comment: Thanks! I'll try that then!